# No dimensions set for key window

Tags: react-native

I am having some issues with react native. It keeps giving me the following error.

[image: error]

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There apparently is [an issue](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1832) with `react-router-flux` since a few days.

You probably need to rollback to the `3.38.0` version before the bug was introduced.

```
yarn add react-native-router-flux@3.38.0
```

If it doesn't work, some people also said that you might need to close all your terminals, delete your build folder and clear your npm cache.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that runs into this. Check to confirm the window passed to get() is a string `Dimensions.get('window')` .

Answer (score 3):

Try closing terminal, deleting ios/build and run again. I had the same issue but now its working.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I ran a different react-native project, but had forgotten to close the terminal window that was running the React Packager.  Once I closed the React Packager terminal window and re-ran `react-native run-android` the error went away.

Comment: I had the same issue, had an RN Console open in Webstorm and running then with an other terminal window gave me this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have an old package manager running from a different project. If so, close it and run again.

Answer (score 1):

Close all terminal
and after use following command in terminal
**npm cache clean**

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

"Close terminal, rerun" worked for me. Seems like this is a recent issue due to the update of react-native.

Answer (score 0):

There are another way to solve this error, I update react-native-cli: 2.0.1 and it works for me.

Comment: I've tried to upgrade `react-native-cli` like you mentioned. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Was it a probability that you had initiated a new project after upgrading `react-native-cli` ? (I've been trying with an Android on Linux)

Comment: On react-native-cli 2.0.1 and still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Dimensions.get('window').width;