# No dimensions set for key window react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Getting No dimensions set for key window with following react versions:

> react-native: 0.56.0, react: 16.4.1, on Android Studio on Windows 10.

Tried all the suggestions from the below thread but no help.
[No dimensions set for key window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825612/no-dimensions-set-for-key-window)

[image: img]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing terminal, deleting ios/build and run again.

I got this answer from [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13758)

It may help you. **If still facing issue let me know**

Comment: thanks! I'm testing on Android simulator and running react-native 0.56.0. Can you share what you mean by close terminal? I've closed react-native window and rebuilt it w/o any resolution.

Comment: ok, I've tried closing and reopening it. let me know if you've any other ideas

Comment: are you using react-native-router-flux/ in your project ?